# Bitcoin sell call options margin

Tags: options, margin, bitcoin

I would like to know why on Deribit the margin requirements for selling call options is so much higher than selling futures.

It’s only about liquidity or there are other reasons?
I guess there are additional calculations on option risk (IV, Gamma… ?)

Comment: Can you show some numbers?